# How can we call action in custom UIView class? Need to reuse UIView class in all View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have created a custom UIView Class. I want to call an action whenever the backButton is called. Need to reuse this UIView class along with action in all view controller. can I able to write in UIView class itself or  view controller?

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (instancetype)init {

   if(self = [super init]){
    //-------------------custom headerView----------------
    self.headerView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 40);
    self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:self.headerView];

    self.backButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,13, 12, 16)];
    [self.backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn.png"]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.backButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(backButtonAction)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.backButton];
   }
   return self;
}
```

BackButton Action

```
-(void)backButtonAction{
   [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that a `UIView` doesn't have a `navigationController` property.  That exists for a view controller.  You might get what you want by having a delegate associated with your view and letting the button action tell the delegate (view controller) to handle the "back" request.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your response. Done with delegates. Its working when I call the view controller . But I what to trigger delegates when i press the uibutton? How can i proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you now have a delegate in your custom view, you can call whatever delegate method you've defined inside `backButtonAction`.

Comment: My problem is that `self.backButton` is not able to call the `backButtionAction` method in `UIView` Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's simple
You have to make Category for `UIViewController` like `UIViewController+Additions`

1. Click `File` -> `New` -> `File`
2. Click `Objective-C file` under `Sources` in `iOS` then Click Next
3. Now under `File Type:` choose either `Category`
4. Then set File Name: `Additions` and set Class: `UIViewController`

---

**UIViewController+Additions.h**
*first create your backbutton function in .h* >>

```
-(void)addBackButton;
```

---

**UIViewController+Additions.m**

```
-(void)addBackButton
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    UIButton *aBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   // [aBtn setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 64)];
    [aBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
    aBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    aBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    aBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    [aBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:65/255.0 blue:96/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aBtn];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aBarBtn;
}

-(void)backButtonAction
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Use Like This:**

just import category in any viewcontroller class `#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     [self addBackButton];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vvk ! Quick and easy answer. can you tell me why i am not able to call actions in uiview class?

Comment: @Balasubramanian The **UIViewController** is the controller part in the MVC design pattern. The viewcontroller's task is to handle navigation between different views, key presses etc. where **UIView** is the object, that we use to display our things.

Comment: You have no idea how much this answer enlightened me in terms of moving a LOT of repetitive code outside of my main UIViewController classes. Can't than you enough for this detailed answer. Thanks a million.

Comment: @MikeCritchley Welcome. enjoy

Comment: @Vvk Thanks for your explanation! Its also easy to override the methods in VC.

Comment: @MikeCritchley Yes. That's true.